# Getting Post Permalink Outside of Loop Not Working

Tags: plugins, php, loop, comments

I'm trying to get post's permalinks outside of the loop via a wordress plugin. Nothing seems to be working. Here is the original code that does not link to any permalink.

```
public function get_comments_count($single){
        if (isset($this->params['comments']) && $this->params['comments'] == 'yes'){
            return '<div id="disquscomments"><a href="'.$permalink.'#disqus_thread">Comments</a></div>';
        } else {
        return null;
        }
    }
```

To get the comments linking to the permalink, I tried adding echo get_permalink within the href link, like so..

```
public function get_comments_count($single){
        if (isset($this->params['comments']) && $this->params['comments'] == 'yes'){
            return '<div id="disquscomments"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>#disqus_thread">Comments</a></div>';
        } else {
        return null;
        }
    }
```

This just returned the link as mysite.com/< ? php echo get_permal... So, I then tried setting a function for permalink and putting it in the href link.. I did this like so...

```
    public function get_comments_count($single){
                $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
        if (isset($this->params['comments']) && $this->params['comments'] == 'yes'){
            return '<div id="disquscomments"><a href="'.$permalink.'#disqus_thread">Comments</a></div>';
        } else {
        return null;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this did not work.  It just returned the link as mysite.com/#disqus_thread without the actual permalink.

I have no idea why this isn't working. :(  Any help would truely be appreciated, and if you would like me to paste the full plugin code via pastebin, I gladfully will!  Please help a bro out!! :)

Comment: Are you referring to the native WordPress function`get_comment_count` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: http://wpseek.com/get_comment_count/ `$single` is the post ID.

Try:

```
public function get_comment_count($single){
    if (isset($this->params['comments']) && $this->params['comments'] == 'yes'){
        return '<div id="disquscomments"><a href="'.get_permalink($single).'#disqus_thread">Comments</a></div>';
    } else {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1658560 Up vote and accept please!

Comment: Of corse, It says 3 more minutes though, be patient. :)

Answer (score -1):

Inside your function, you are outside of scope from your loop. You should call the function with the ID of the post, so add a 2nd parameter:

```
public function get_comments_count($single, $postid){
     $permalink = get_permalink($postid);
    if (isset($this->params['comments']) && $this->params['comments'] == 'yes'){
        return '<div id="disquscomments"><a     href="'.$permalink.'#disqus_thread">Comments</a></div>';
    } else {
    return null;
    }
}
```